# relative memory locations of local variables

Tags: c++, c

This is one of those annoying questions but I'd just like to know for the sake of knowing.

When declaring local function variables, does the order of declaration make any difference as to where these variables will exist in memory relative to one another? Can anything be determined about the relative memory locations of a and b (below) based on their order of declaration?

I read that the order does make a  difference in that variables declared later (like b below) will have lower memory addresses than those declared before it (like a below). However, I've had varying results based on my experimentation.

Is this something that is completely random or can the relative memory locations be determined based on order of declaration (ie, "&a will always be a lower memory address than &b")?

For example:

```
int func()
{
    int a = 0;
    char b = 'C';

    b = 'D';
    return ++a;
}
```

Comment: Your example, in particular, is likely to be optimized away to `int func() { return 1; }`, with no memory at all reserved for local variables.

Comment: Many variables don't even *have* memory addresses, if they're allocated to registers.

Comment: Nothing is "completely random" :) And chances are, that e.g. after `int foo[4]; int bar;` the expression `foo[4]` has the value of `bar`. Such things are helpful for building compilers, understanding/performing exploits and the like, but any assumption on something like that may fail with a different compiler, on a different platform, with a new compiler version, or with different optimization levels. The standard don't guarantee anything here. Not even that such objects are stored next to each other or are addressable at all.

Comment: @mafso yes! it is a security-related question - if b had been a char array instead of just a char, and user input was blindly strcpy'd into b. i'm just wondering if the order of declaration would "protect" the value of a from a potential buffer overflow.

Comment: Maybe this will "fix" a security issue (in the sense, that it's not longer exploitable on a given platform with a given compiler and so on), maybe not. At least, it's not a fix of a bug. A fix is to validate user input and take care to not overflow buffers.

Answer (score 3):

In a nutshell, it is entirely up to the compiler. It also depends on the target platform, optimization options etc.

Furthermore, a variable might not even have an address (because it's been optimized away, exists in a register etc).

In your specific example, my compiler does not allocate any storage for either `a` or `b`, so nothing can be said about their relative addresses.